# Please, would you like to explain the [なす] in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

every one. I am trying to translate japanese text. But there's something male me confuse and curious. The nasu in this sentence, woul you like to explain it.

海の岸辺に緑 [なす] 樫の木

It's really make me curious and confuse. Is it midorina + su. So what the function of su there? Or its midorina+nasu. Nasu function?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question shows a lack of personal research. Try searching for 緑なす on a decent search engine.

Comment: ^ 「緑なす」だけでググったら緑色のナスのレシピばっかりだったｗｗ　「緑なす　意味」でググったらこれ出てきたけど　→　https://kotobank.jp/word/緑なす-391736

Comment: 確かに「意味」も加えて検索していた。